# Using pg_connect returning false on php-fpm / CentOS6

Tags: php, postgresql, centos6, php-pgsql

I'm now developing a site on CentOS/nginx/postgresql/php(php-fpm).

#### The problem:

And I have such a database connection code which blocks:

```
$dbcon = pg_connect(
    "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=shex_utf8 user=webmaster password=webmaster"
);
var_dump($dbcon);
```

It only return false when I run that code on visiting `http://example.com/dbcon.php`

I haven't seen any error or warning displayed.

#### Direct php script executing: SUCCESS

But if i call:

```
php < dbcon.php
```

It was returning:

> resource(5) of type (pgsql link)

#### Using httpd: FAIL

I changed the http server from nginx to httpd, the problem still exists.

#### Using spawn-fcgi: SUCCESS

And then I stop the php-fpm service, and run a spawn-fcgi instead, there was no problem.

---

#### Question:

What's the matter with php-fpm? How can I configure the *php-fpm* and work around the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was because of a selinux setting.

Worked around by:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
```